# Craft front-end forms not working with Angularjs app

Tags: form, registration

I'm making a site with Craft CMS/Angularjs. I'm using angular to filter and display entries on the index page and it's working good so far except for one thing. The login/register/entry form's all don't function at all. If I remove ng-app from the html tag they work just fine so it's definitely angular that's causing this issue.

Here's my login form on the main page:

```
{% if currentUser %}
        You are logged in as <strong>{{ currentUser.friendlyName }}</strong>
        <a href="/logout">logout</a>

    {% else %}

    <form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/login">

        <h3><label for="loginName">Username</label></h3>
        <input id="loginName" type="text" name="loginName">

        <h3><label for="password">Password</label></h3>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password">

        <input type="submit" value="Login">

        {% if errorMessage is defined %}
            <p>{{ errorMessage }}</p>
        {% endif %}
        <p>Please login or <a href="/register">register</a></p>
    </form>

    {% endif %}
```

If anyone with experience using angular and craft together can chime in that'll be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out. Turns out a form won't submit in an Angular app if it doesn't have an action specified.

Comment: By omitting the action attribute, all a form does is submit itself to the same url it resides on. As a workaround, you can use `craft.request.url` as the action.